# AlarmReceiver & Notification Method causing crash?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently trying to set up the date picker and time picker to fire out a notification when the time is reached. I have created a method in MainActivity and this is being called from AlarmReceiver. Every time the timer reaches the set amount, the application is crashing and no errors are being shown in logcat.

I know it is something to do with this method being called from AlarmReceiver, i just don't know what the problems is. This method is also currently linked to a button which is working when pressed (buttonStopAlarm) fires a notification when pressed as wanted) so overall the method does work, it's just not working when being called from another class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**AlarmReceiver**

```
package servicealarmdemo.test2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    main.addNotification();

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing this `MainActivity main = new MainActivity();` you are just creating an instance of `MainActivity` but it will not have it's `context` mean `this` which is basically provided when `Activity` is started by the `OS`

so move you `Notification code` in your `Receiver` and use `arg0` as `context`

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    Context cxt;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cxt = arg0;

        //main.addNotification();
        addNotification();

    }

    public void addNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(cxt)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent)
                        .setContentTitle("Achieve Alert!")
                        .setContentText("This is a reminder for your deadline!");

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(cxt, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(cxt, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)cxt.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have moved that over to AlarmReceiver. There is only one error showing up now for getSystemService.  Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)'

Comment: @ZenoX use `cxt.getSystemService..`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have just tested it and notifications are now being fired when the time has been reached! Also thank you for explaining about the MainActivity code being an instance, it has really helped my understanding!

Comment: @ZenoX i am glad that i could help , thanks for the appreciation , happy coding